# Redirect Status Code 302 between Tomcat and IIS 7.0 is not properly handled by the isapi redirector

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis-7, http-status-code-302, isapi-redirect

We recently installed a web application under Tomcat 6 which is connected over the isapi redirector interface (see http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) to an IIS 7 server. The connector works properly in every case, except for some pages in the web application that return a status 302, with a new location to redirect for.

The browser gets the 302 back and requests the new location, but the IIS web server does not forward the request to the Tomcat server and returns a 404 error instead, even though the uri worker map looks correct for me.

The corresponding uri worker rule is:

`/WebClientServlet/*=worker1`

and the location url of the new location looks like the following:

`http://localhost/WebClientServlet/SBS/cmd:editContent2/workflow:false/articleSearch:false/confirmed:false/objectID:131294/---/fpse/db:test/objectID:131294/Copy+of+0001-Intranet+Home-main-ip+%28DE%29`

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. The HTTP status code was actually a 404.11, which means (under IIS 7) that double escaped sequences are not allowed. There is a new feature introduced in IIS 7 called double escaped URL filtering. It is a default security filter, which denies to load any URL that contain double escaped sequences. In order to solve the problem, switch the feature off for the web site which is used to access the tomcat application over isapi-redirector. See more under http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the ISAPI redirector. Up until today it is what I have been using. Check out the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting) for IIS7. [Here](http://dannybaggs.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/iis7-tomcat-application-request-routing/) is a walk through on how to set it up. If you want to use host headers look [here](http://www.charlesstrahan.com/blog/2010/09/30/configuring-teamcity-in-iis-7-5/).